# Android:WI-FI broadcast receiver control the time of execution

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, rssi

I'm using broadcast receiver to scan the RSSI change ,well in every change i had to do some computings. But the broadcast receiver is scanning too fast ,so it can not do the computing task. I know that ,when it detect a change in the RSSI it start a new loop. How can i stop the execution of the broadcast for a little periode to do some calculation, and then resume.
this is my BroadcastReceiver :

```
private BroadcastReceiver myRssiChangeReceiver  = new BroadcastReceiver(){

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    Toast.makeText(Position.this,"MyTag distance "+ "onReceive", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   (WifiManager)Position.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiMan.startScan();
  newRssi = wifiMan.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();

  Toast.makeText(Position.this, ""+newRssi, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  int size = listCursorReçue.size();
  for (int j=0;j<size;j++){
     int[] ligne = listCursorReçue.get(j);
     Toast.makeText(Position.this,"MyTag BroadcastReceiver "+ ligne[2] + ligne [3] +"loguer ligne"+ligne.length, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    distanceTemp = (long) Math.sqrt((rssi1-rssiOp1)*(rssi1-rssiOp1)+(rssi2-rssiOp2)*(rssi2-rssiOp2)+(rssi3-rssiOp3)*(rssi3-rssiOp3));
}




}};
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your BroadcastReceiver is registered on main thread(UI thread), then it will be killed after 10 seconds. You can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29).

If you wan't to do something which takes much time you have two options:

1. Use another thread for receiver
2. Start a `Service` from your onReceive and perform long-running task within a `Service`.

I would go with second option. That'll give you more clean and flexible architecture.

**UPD**

More on Services [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

There's a range of options with Services. So I sugges you to learn more about Service lifecycle and then choose what fits best for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for replying.As you said,i'll choose the second methode,as i'm new to brodcastreceiver,i did a little reserch about it.I found an article with this : Automatically starting Services from a Receivers. where i have to add a permission ` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
`  and use this code `public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // assumes WordService is a registered service
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WordService.class);
    context.startService(intent);
  }`where do i have to add my calculation part?Thanks

Comment: Thank you ,i read document ,and i tryed an example ,and it worked :) .but i would like to know if i coul send data to the service like normal intent like this : `Intent intent1 = new Intent (arg0,ServiceCalcul.class); 
   Bundle bundleObject = new Bundle();
   bundleObject.putSerializable("key", (Serializable) newRssi);
  intent1.putExtras(bundleObject);
  startActivityForResult(intent1,0);`

Comment: Each time you call startService(intent) you can create a new Intent and pass data. Then in onStartCommand you can handle the intent.

Comment: THANKS :D yes it worked too  `Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(arg0,ServiceCalcul.class);
      serviceIntent.putExtra("key", newRssi);
      arg0.startService(serviceIntent);`                          and in onStartCommand  `int rssi = intent.getIntExtra("key", 0);`

Comment: I heard that service that runs from broadcast receiver runs with low priority and it is very restricted. what do you think about it?